# C# - wpf: start and close instance of calculator.exe or explorer.exe

Tags: c#, process.start

I am trying to make an application that starts on windows in order to have a controlled environment, but when I try to open explorer or the windows calculator, the process opens and closes instantly even if the calculator actually remains open and consequently does not I can add and remove the application to the navBar.

If I go to check in the active processes I actually do not find the pid of the process that I started

How can I manage these two windows processes?

This is my code:

```
            var process = Process.Start(program.Path);

            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            // Add icon in bar
            var item = AddIconToApplicationBar(program, process, true);
            var bg = new BackgroundWorker();

            bg.DoWork += (ss, ee) =>
            {
                _logger.Information($"User:{User} Started Program:{program.Name} Auto Start:{autoStart}");
                process?.WaitForExit();
            };

            bg.RunWorkerCompleted += (ss, ee) =>
            {
                _logger.Information($"Exit Program:{program.Name} exitCode: {process?.ExitCode}");

                // Remove icon in bar
                RemoveIconToApplicationBar(item);

                RemoveRunningProgram(process);

                switch (program.Recovery)
                {
                    case Recovery.NoAction:
                        break;
                    case Recovery.UseExitCode:
                        if (process?.ExitCode != 0)
                        {
                            _logger.Information($"Program {program.Name} restarted exitCode: {process?.ExitCode}");
                            StartProcess(program);
                        }

                        break;
                    case Recovery.RestartAlways:
                        _logger.Information($"Program {program.Name} restarted exitCode: {process?.ExitCode}");
                        StartProcess(program);
                        break;
                }
            };

            bg.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: calc.exe starts another exe and then quits immediately. What do you use to start Explorer (what is the exact path you use)?

Comment: Calculator: C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe
Explorer: C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe

Comment: Use Process Monitor and Process Explorer to see what actually happens. Running calc.exe actually starts something like "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.2103.8.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe" and then calc.exe immediately terminates. This does not happen for Explorer.exe on my machine, but maybe you have different settings than I do.

Comment: I found the folder ... but inside it I have a folder named deleted